# Javascript: Memory control - watch on what it's particularly used

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to track down(profiling) on what particularly memory were used.

For example this object eats this much memory, this one this much etc.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Chrome you are able to make a heap snapshot:

1. Open Developer Tools (F12)
2. Go to 'Profiles' tab
3. Click an 'eye' icon to make a snapshot
4. Browse created snapshot for desired object

Comment: Yea i know. But it's too hard to understand. :D Any book or anything would help. :)

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers you can. For instance, in Google Chrome the location `about:memory` will give you detailed information about memory usage.

Comment: Isn't it just displays overall used memory.

Comment: It gives you some amount of detail, but I think @kdzwinel's way is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tools available for this. One of which is [JavaScript Memory Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/javascript/memory/feature.html), it's a paid for product, but has a free trial.

Mozilla also has a list of useful js performance tools [listed here](http://www.mozilla.org/performance/tools.html).

Comment: Wow i think JavaScript Memory Validator is just what i need. :)

Comment: It's madness. Can Firefox eat up to 800 memory? It drops after some period of time. Could it be a leak or it's normal new Firefox behavior? Because inside IE and Chrome everything works fine. No memory leaks detected.

Comment: @Beck This is generally normal Firefox behaviour, if there's memory available it's free to use it; and generally does so (I believe it creates bitmaps of pages to make scrolling more fluent, amongst other things). The only reliable way to determine the footprint of your javascript is to use a profiler. Disregard any overall memory use metrics.